# Stop 3D objects moving when windows is resized [XNA/WinForms/C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d, xna, projection

I have an XNA windows inside a a windows form, and I am running into a problem when I resize the window.

The behaviour I want is for the rendered cube to not move at all. So if there was a second cube offscreen to the right, and the user resized the window to the right, then the second cube would come into view. So basically resizing the window has no effect on the rendered elements at all.

But when I resize the window, for example drag it right, the cube also moves to the right sad.png
And when I drag the window down the cube zooms in slowly.

Here is my draw code for each quad of the cube:

```
GraphicsDevice dev = Core.Device;

dev.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
dev.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

dev.SetVertexBuffer(_vb);
dev.Indices = _ib;

effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 150), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, dev.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.1f, 10000.0f);
effect.World = Matrix.Identity;

effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
effect.Texture = Texture;

effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
dev.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, vertices.Length, 0, indices.Length / 3);
```

I am using the winforms/xna sample from the xna website. When the window is resized the device is reset and the backbuffer width and height get set to the xna windows width and height.

This means the `Viewport.AspectRatio` gets updated and the 3d cubes do not get stretched. Now I just need their position to not change.

Does anyone know what else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because XNA knows nothing of your Windows Forms window. This means that it doesn't know how to scale it, so naturally it will just scale it to be 1x1

The easiest way to accomplish what you're asking, would be to render everything to a RenderTarget of say 1920x1080, and then draw that RenderTarget with the current Window width/height.

Pseudo code:

```
public void Draw(params)
{
    RenderTarget2D renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 1920, 1080); // Might want some parameters, dunno
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);

    // Render stuff as usual

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); // Resets it

    spritebatch.Begin();
    spritebatch.Draw(renderTarget.GetTexture(), new Rectangle(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight), params...);
    spritebatch.End();
}
```

I don't recall if these are the exact method names, but it's something like that.

**Explanation**: What you're essentially doing, is rendering everything onto a temporary in-memory buffer (similar to a drawing in photoshop). Then after doing that, you can work with it as if it was any other 2D texture. That also means that you can draw it onto the screen, and transform it as you like (In your case, squish it down to a 800x600, if that is your current WinForms size);